# Highlight GridView cell like Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'm trying to figure out how to highlight an entire GridView cell when you press it, just like in the Google Play Store. Here's an image of what I'm trying to do (Roaring Skies cell is what I'm trying to accomplish):

[image]

I know that you can use a selector for Images/Views, but this only changes the background color and will not overlay the image that is in the cell (unless there's some special trick/switch that I haven't found yet). I am trying to overlay a semi-transparent color over (not below the image) the entire contents of the cell and a selector does not appear to do that. I also know that you can use .setColorFilter() with an OnTouchListener, but that only works for Drawables (as far as I understand) and I think it would be a pain to implement with a GridView. In the Google Play Store the entire cell is highlighted and it has multiple different views in it.

Currently, I have a GridView setup with a custom background to give it a card-like appearance. It has an ImageView in it with a couple TextViews, but I can't figure out how to highlight the entire GridView cell (overlay a semi-transparent color). Normally I would provide code, but in this case I'm not sure it would help since what I've currently got is pretty standard. Any ideas about how this is accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

use attribute drawSelectorOnTop="false" in xml.

or try `mGridview.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true)`

Hope it help.

Comment: Sorry, it's drawSelectorOnTop="true", if you are not using ListFragment, All the best. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

It can be achieve by **Selector**.

Use **selector** on the root layout of grid_cell_item as a **background**.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/artists_list_backgroundcolor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_grid_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_grid_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/home_grid_img"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**artists_list_backgroundcolor.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/white" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@color/itemselected" />
</selector>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="itemselected">#EDEDED</color>

</resources>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but this will not achieve the effect that I am looking for. In my comments above, I mentioned that a selector would not work. This only highlights the background, not the foreground and all items in the cell view like the picture above shows.

Comment: @Jason can you try once and tell me wats the problem in this. I ll try to reach close to that.

Comment: @Jason you can change the hover effect of all item in the cell. For that you need to write separate selector. As per my assumption in google play they changed the background itself. That makes the effect to all item in the cell.

Comment: I tried your code before I posted my reply and I had tried similar implementations prior to posting this question (hence the statement in my question about selectors). In ALL of the implementations that I have tried, that use a background selector, the background color changes when the cell is pressed, but that color does NOT get overlayed on top of the image that is in the cell. If you are getting different results I'm not sure why. As far as the hover effect goes, I really don't think that's what is being used in the Play Store. A tested, working example would be greatly appreciated.